# Responsive layout in C# Xamarin Android, how?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, responsive-design

I'm making an Android application in Xamarin. 
I want to make it responsive, so I need to get the screen size value (this worked). Now I need to send this to another activity, but I can't get the value because I first need to open a resource layout.

```
string width1 = Intent.GetStringExtra("width") ?? "Data not available";
width = width1.ToString();
string height2 = Intent.GetStringExtra("height") ?? "Data not available";
height = height2.ToString();

// Set our view from the "recepten" layout resource
if (Convert.ToInt32(width) <= 350 && Convert.ToInt32(height) <= 420)
{
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.login);
}
else
{
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.loginSmall);
}
```

I tried this (isn't working), but I can't get another layout when another layout already opened.

Does anyone know any how?

Comment: Why are you sending dimensions to activity, you can always take current value.

Comment: What do you mean with dimensions?

Comment: I mean screen size

Comment: width and height is the size of the screen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are on the wrong track. You should never need to query the actual screen size for a responsive layout.

You can define different layouts for different screen sizes and android will pick the best one for the device.

To do this create a couple of layout-folders prefexed with "large", "xlarge" etc. as described in the [official android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support):

```
Resources/layout/my_layout.xml // layout for normal screen size ("default") 
Resources/layout-large/my_layout.xml // layout for large screen size    
Resources/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml // layout for extra-large screen size
Resources/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra-large in landscape orientation
```

A call to `SetContentView` contains the neccesary logic to pick the right layout for the screen size of the device.

Read [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) more information about supporting multiple screen sizes.

Comment: This isn't code. This is an example of the file-structure of your project (the files you see in the panel on the right in Visual Studio). So you need to create more xml files.

Comment: So if I make 4 maps (layout-small, layout-normal etc.) Then Android will automatically choose the best?

Comment: Also I need to use support-screens?

Comment: Yes Android will choose the best. The happens "internally" inside the SetContentView function of Android.